# count and collect operations are taking much time on empty spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating an empty spark data frame with spark.createDataFrame([], schema)  and then I am adding rows from lists, but accessing the data frame ( count-collect) are taking too much time from usual on this dataframe.

function dataframe.count() on 1000 rows on a data frame created from Csv files is taking 300 ms but on the empty data frame created from schema it's taking 4 seconds.
Here this difference is coming from?

```
schema = StructType([StructField('Average_Power',FloatType(),True),
StructField('Average_Temperature',FloatType(),True),                     
StructField('ClientId',StringType(),True),])

df = df_event_spark = spark.createDataFrame([], schema) 
df.count()
```

Is there any way to create an empty spark data frame more optimized way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the recommended way in pyspark.

There is a certain overehead in staring up a Spark App or running things from a Notebook. 100 rows is tiny, but the overhead of running a Spark App etc. is relatively large w.r.t. to such a small volume.